# failure in making bootable win 10 64 bit with woeusb

Tags: boot

Please help me to fix this issue:

```
Error: File "/media/woeusb_source_1544544327_15932/sources/install.wim" in source image has exceed the FAT32 Filesystem 4GiB Single File Size Limitation and cannot be installed.
You must specify a different --target-filesystem.
Refer: https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/wiki/Limitations#fat32-filesystem-4gib-single-file-size-limitation for more info.
Unmounting and removing "/media/woeusb_source_1544544327_15932"...
You may now safely detach the target device
```

I also formatted the pendrive in NTFS and the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

Take care of two thing and try again.

1. A USB drive with at least 6 GB of space.
2. Format it in NTFS.